# Check if the item in list or sub-list

Tags: list, scheme

I want to use the check function to check if the item is in the list or the sub-list.
But the error really confuse me. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
(define check
 (lambda(item lis)
  (cond((null? lis) #f)
       (else(if(pair? (car lis)) 
               (if(check item (car lis)) #t (check item (cdr lis))) 
               (if(equal? item (car list)) #t (check item (cdr lis))))))))


> (check 'a '(a b))
. . car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: #<procedure:list>
```

Comment: You `(car list)` and `list` is a `procedure`, not a list. That gives a contract violation. Perhaps your argument `lis` was the intended argument?

Comment: For the code that you're trying to write, you might find similar questions useful, e.g., [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19249879/1281433).

Comment: Also note that `(if(check item (car lis)) #t (check item (cdr lis)))` simplifies to `(or (check item (car lis)) (check item (cdr list))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks, you are right. I just begin to learn scheme, have a lot work to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in here:

```
(equal? item (car list))
```

It should be:

```
(equal? item (car lis))
```

Notice that `list` is a procedure, and the parameter in your code is called `lis`.

Comment: @user2891085 Are you using an IDE such as DrRacket?  When I load your code into DrRacket and execute the `(check 'a '(a b))`, DrRacket highlights the problematic form immediately.  I ask because the error form that you're pointing out has the same form that I've seen in DrRacket.  E.g., see [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/jSSj9tA).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor What I use is DRraket.. It seems not as powerful as DrRacket

Comment: @ChuangFu Any chance you can provide a link to this DRraket?  I searched for that on Google, but all that comes up is autocorrected links to DrRacket and typos for DrRacket.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Sorry. What I use is DrRacket(version 5.3.6 ). But it did not highlights my error..