# Search element in a list or sublist in scheme

Tags: scheme

A function which will take an item and a list and return a boolean of whether or not the item was found on the list or any sublists.

```
(define is-present?
  (lambda (item lis)
    (if (null? lis) #f
       (if (eqv? item (car lis))
       #t
       (is-present? (item (cdr lis)))))))
```

I am able to search the element in a plain list but when there is a sublist in the list it fails.

Comment: You may find [Check if the item in list or sub-list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19436282/1281433) useful, as well as [Find an element of list in lists in list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19249879/1281433).

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a sublist, you need to recurse on this sublist.

```
(define search
  (lambda (item lst)
    (cond ((null? lst)
           #f)
          ((pair? (car lst))
           (or (search item (car lst))
               (search item (cdr lst))))
          (else
            (or (eqv? item (car lst))
                (search item (cdr lst)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
(define (present? item list)
    (cond ((or (not (list? list)) (null? list)) #f)
          ((let ((x (car list))) (or (eqv? item x) (present? item x))) #t)
          (else (present? item (cdr list)))))
```

This is what we're doing:

1. We first check whether `list` is actually a list. If it's not a list then we return `#f`.
2. We then check whether `list` is empty. If it's empty then we return `#f`.
3. Next we check whether the `car` of `list` is `item`. If it is then we return `#t`.
4. Then we check whether the `car` of `list` contains `item`. If it does then we return `#t`.
5. Finally if nothing else checked out then we return whether the `cdr` of `list` contains `item`.

The `present?` function checks whether `item` is a member of `list` or a sublist of `list`:

```
(present? 0 '(1 2 3 4))     => #f
(present? 3 '(1 2 3 4))     => #t
(present? 0 '((1 2) (3 4))) => #f
(present? 3 '((1 2) (3 4))) => #t
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take special action if the `car` of `lis` is itself a list.  You code is lacking a check for that condition.  Try this:

```
(define (isPresent? item lis)
  (and (not (null? lis))
       (let ((head (car lis)))
         (or (eqv? item head)
             (and (pair? head) (isPresent? item head))  ;; <= your code missed this
             (isPresent? item (cdr lis))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Aye! That's my homework question.

And this is my answer :

```
(define present 
(lambda (x list)
(cond ((or (not (list? list)) (null? list)) #f)
      ((or (eqv? x (car list)) (present x (car list))) #t)
      (else (present x (cdr list))))))
```